# spamassassin complaining twice a week: cannot open file

Tags: postfix, spamassassin

Our postfix/spamssassin complains irregularly but at lease twice a week via mail with the following message:

```
/etc/cron.daily/spamassassin:
Cannot open file /var/lib/spamassassin/3.004002/updates_spamassassin_org/1906307.tar.gz: No such file or directory at /usr/bin/sa-update line 1603.
Jan  2 05:39:18.671 [21712] dbg: logger: adding facilities: all
Jan  2 05:39:18.674 [21712] dbg: logger: logging level is DBG
Jan  2 05:39:18.674 [21712] dbg: generic: SpamAssassin version 3.4.2
Jan  2 05:39:18.674 [21712] dbg: generic: Perl 5.018002, PREFIX=/usr, DEF_RULES_DIR=/usr/share/spamassassin, LOCAL_RULES_DIR=/etc/spamassassin, LOCAL_STATE_DIR=/var/lib/spamassassin
Jan  2 05:39:18.674 [21712] dbg: config: timing enabled
Jan  2 05:39:18.678 [21712] dbg: config: score set 0 chosen.
Jan  2 05:39:18.681 [21712] dbg: util: running in taint mode? yes
Jan  2 05:39:18.681 [21712] dbg: util: taint mode: deleting unsafe environment variables, resetting PATH
Jan  2 05:39:18.681 [21712] dbg: util: PATH included '/usr/local/bin', keeping
Jan  2 05:39:18.681 [21712] dbg: util: PATH included '/usr/bin', keeping
Jan  2 05:39:18.681 [21712] dbg: util: PATH included '/bin', keeping
Jan  2 05:39:18.681 [21712] dbg: util: PATH included '/usr/local/games', keeping
Jan  2 05:39:18.681 [21712] dbg: util: PATH included '/usr/games', keeping
Jan  2 05:39:18.682 [21712] dbg: util: final PATH set to: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
Jan  2 05:39:19.034 [21712] dbg: diag: perl platform: 5.018002 linux
Jan  2 05:39:19.034 [21712] dbg: diag: [...] module installed: Digest::SHA, version 5.84_01
Jan  2 05:39:19.034 [21712] dbg: diag: [...] module installed: HTML::Parser, version 3.71
Jan  2 05:39:19.034 [21712] dbg: diag: [...] module installed: Net::DNS, version 0.68
Jan  2 05:39:19.034 [21712] dbg: diag: [...] module installed: NetAddr::IP, version 4.071
Jan  2 05:39:19.034 [21712] dbg: diag: [...] module installed: Time::HiRes, version 1.9725
Jan  2 05:39:19.035 [21712] dbg: diag: [...] module installed: Archive::Tar, version 1.90
Jan  2 05:39:19.035 [21712] dbg: diag: [...] module installed: IO::Zlib, version 1.10
Jan  2 05:39:19.035 [21712] dbg: diag: [...] module not installed: Digest::SHA1 ('require' failed)
Jan  2 05:39:19.035 [21712] dbg: diag: [...] module installed: MIME::Base64, version 3.13
Jan  2 05:39:19.035 [21712] dbg: diag: [...] module installed: DB_File, version 1.827
Jan  2 05:39:19.035 [21712] dbg: diag: [...] module installed: Net::SMTP, version 2.31
Jan  2 05:39:19.035 [21712] dbg: diag: [...] module installed: Mail::SPF, version v2.009
Jan  2 05:39:19.035 [21712] dbg: diag: [...] module not installed: Geo::IP ('require' failed)
Jan  2 05:39:19.035 [21712] dbg: diag: [...] module not installed: Net::CIDR::Lite ('require' failed)
Jan  2 05:39:19.035 [21712] dbg: diag: [...] module installed: Razor2::Client::Agent, version 2.84
Jan  2 05:39:19.035 [21712] dbg: diag: [...] module not installed: IO::Socket::IP ('require' failed)
Jan  2 05:39:19.035 [21712] dbg: diag: [...] module installed: IO::Socket::INET6, version 2.71
Jan  2 05:39:19.036 [21712] dbg: diag: [...] module installed: IO::Socket::SSL, version 1.965
Jan  2 05:39:19.036 [21712] dbg: diag: [...] module installed: Compress::Zlib, version 2.06
Jan  2 05:39:19.036 [21712] dbg: diag: [...] module installed: Mail::DKIM, version 0.4
Jan  2 05:39:19.036 [21712] dbg: diag: [...] module installed: DBI, version 1.63
Jan  2 05:39:19.036 [21712] dbg: diag: [...] module installed: Getopt::Long, version 2.39
Jan  2 05:39:19.036 [21712] dbg: diag: [...] module installed: LWP::UserAgent, version 6.05
Jan  2 05:39:19.036 [21712] dbg: diag: [...] module installed: HTTP::Date, version 6.02
Jan  2 05:39:19.036 [21712] dbg: diag: [...] module installed: Encode::Detect::Detector, version 1.01
Jan  2 05:39:19.036 [21712] dbg: diag: [...] module not installed: Net::Patricia ('require' failed)
Jan  2 05:39:19.036 [21712] dbg: diag: [...] module installed: Net::DNS::Nameserver, version 970
Jan  2 05:39:19.037 [21712] dbg: diag: [...] module installed: BSD::Resource, version 1.2907
Jan  2 05:39:19.037 [21712] dbg: ignore: using a test message to lint rules
Jan  2 05:39:19.037 [21712] dbg: config: using "/etc/spamassassin" for site rules pre files
Jan  2 05:39:19.037 [21712] dbg: config: read file /etc/spamassassin/init.pre
Jan  2 05:39:19.038 [21712] dbg: config: read file /etc/spamassassin/sa-compile.pre
Jan  2 05:39:19.038 [21712] dbg: config: read file /etc/spamassassin/v310.pre
Jan  2 05:39:19.038 [21712] dbg: config: read file /etc/spamassassin/v312.pre
Jan  2 05:39:19.038 [21712] dbg: config: read file /etc/spamassassin/v320.pre
Jan  2 05:39:19.038 [21712] dbg: config: read file /etc/spamassassin/v330.pre
Jan  2 05:39:19.038 [21712] dbg: config: read file /etc/spamassassin/v340.pre
Jan  2 05:39:19.039 [21712] dbg: config: read file /etc/spamassassin/v341.pre
Jan  2 05:39:19.039 [21712] dbg: config: read file /etc/spamassassin/v342.pre
Jan  2 05:39:19.039 [21712] dbg: config: using "/var/lib/spamassassin/3.004002" for sys rules pre files
Jan  2 05:39:19.039 [21712] dbg: config: using "/var/lib/spamassassin/3.004002" for default rules dir
Jan  2 05:39:19.040 [21712] dbg: config: read file /var/lib/spamassassin/3.004002/updates_spamassassin_org.cf
Jan  2 05:39:19.040 [21712] dbg: config: using "/etc/spamassassin" for site rules dir
Jan  2 05:39:19.040 [21712] dbg: config: read file /etc/spamassassin/65_debian.cf
Jan  2 05:39:19.040 [21712] dbg: config: read file /etc/spamassassin/local.cf
Jan  2 05:39:19.041 [21712] dbg: config: using "/var/lib/spamassassin/.spamassassin/user_prefs" for user prefs file
Jan  2 05:39:19.041 [21712] dbg: config: read file /var/lib/spamassassin/.spamassassin/user_prefs
Jan  2 05:39:19.042 [21712] dbg: plugin: loading Mail::SpamAssassin::Plugin::URIDNSBL from @INC
Jan  2 05:39:19.048 [21712] dbg: plugin: loading Mail::SpamAssassin::Plugin::Hashcash from @INC
Jan  2 05:39:19.051 [21712] dbg: plugin: loading Mail::SpamAssassin::Plugin::SPF from @INC
Jan  2 05:39:19.057 [21712] dbg: plugin: loading Mail::SpamAssassin::Plugin::TextCat from @INC
Jan  2 05:39:19.059 [21712] dbg: textcat: loading languages file /usr/share/spamassassin/languages
Jan  2 05:39:19.117 [21712] dbg: textcat: loaded 73 language models
Jan  2 05:39:19.122 [21712] dbg: plugin: loading Mail::SpamAssassin::Plugin::Rule2XSBody from @INC
Jan  2 05:39:19.126 [21712] dbg: plugin: loading Mail::SpamAssassin::Plugin::Pyzor from @INC
Jan  2 05:39:19.129 [21712] dbg: pyzor: local tests only, disabling Pyzor
Jan  2 05:39:19.129 [21712] dbg: plugin: loading Mail::SpamAssassin::Plugin::Razor2 from @INC
Jan  2 05:39:19.131 [21712] dbg: razor2: local tests only, skipping Razor
Jan  2 05:39:19.132 [21712] dbg: plugin: loading Mail::SpamAssassin::Plugin::SpamCop from @INC
Jan  2 05:39:19.134 [21712] dbg: reporter: local tests only, disabling SpamCop
```

(The actual error message is a lot longer, can post on request). The problem is obviously related to daily updates, i assume automatic ones, but - since most of the times it seems to be working - what is exactly the problem? Failed download? No write permissions?

Is there any setting that my help us track down this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is bug, more details please see
https://bz.apache.org/SpamAssassin/show_bug.cgi?id=7662

Comment: Thanks! Actually ubuntu only has .deb up to 3.4.2, how do i update manually?

Comment: You can get this [patch](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/spamassassin/branches/3.4/sa-update.raw?r1=1842326&r2=1842325&pathrev=1842326&view=patch)

Comment: Thanks! Actually how do i apply this patch? The sa-update.raw file does not exist here. Do i have to build the module?

Comment: I think you should try update ubuntu and see if there have update fix packages for spamassassin by using command sudo apt update

If you want to update manual then please read [this](https://opensource.com/article/18/8/diffs-patches) for understand diffs and patches

Comment: Sorry, i did not ask very well: i do know about diffs and patches (and generate git PR from time to time), so this is not the point.

I cloned the SA github repo and issued perl Makefile.PL but is does not build, "cannot touch 'rules/72_active.cf' at Makefile.PL line 335, <STDIN> line 1."

Comment: You can patch it direct to sa-update

Comment: Thanks once more, i patched and no more error messages so far. Will post here if they come up again!